# Sitecore: "You cannot drag an item onto itself" error when clicking on an item in IE

Tags: sitecore

After updating a Sitecore instance from 6.3 to 6.6, we get the following error message when clicking on an item in the content editor:

[image]

This only happens with the Internet Explorer. What could be the cause for this?

Comment: Try reloading the page without browser cache by pressing Ctrl+F5.

Comment: Tried that already, didn't help.

Comment: Does this happen on other machines as well?

Comment: Yes, it does. Mainly on IE 10.

Comment: Which revision of 6.6 did you upgrade to? https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/686113

Comment: Sitecore 6.6.0 (rev. 140410)

Comment: Make sure compatibility mode is off is the only thing I can suggest.

Comment: Do you mean the IE compatiblity mode? That's off.